# Can I turn off ASP.NET MVC changing backslash in URL params to forward slash?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a WebAPI method to retrieve some user details based on an Windows Logon:

```
[Route("api/user/{username}/details")]
public IHttpActionResult(string username)
{
    // ...
}
```

Suppose I am user `arjan` on the `MYCORP` domain, then some javascript on my webpage would issue a `GET` to `http://myserver/api/user/MYCORP\arjan/details`.

This route never gets correctly resolved, as IIS, ASP.NET or something will rewrite the `\` to a `/` before routing.

I can see in Fiddler that the correct URL is requested, but errorpage returned from IIS, clearly states it didn't find `http://myserver/api/user/MYCORP\arjan/details`.

I'm using MVC 5/.NET 4.5/IIS 7.5/VS2015/Windows 7.

So: why is my webserver turning the request URI

```
http://myserver/api/user/MYCORP\arjan/details
```

Into

```
http://myserver/api/user/MYCORP/arjan/details
```

And how can I turn it off?

Percent-encoding the `\` to `%5C` doesn't resolve the issue, the decoding seems to happen very early at the server.

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Route parameter with slash "/" in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url), which asks about using `/` as a URL parameter. This question is about why IIS/ASP.NET changes `\` to `/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Route parameter with slash "/" in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url)

Comment: You could also encode the username in the url

Comment: @jrummell: I tried replacing the "\" with `%5C`, but the decoding seems to happen very  early at the server. On the server, in MVC I never get to see the encoded values...

Comment: Did you ever get an acceptable solution for this issue?

Comment: @JaredStroeb: Sorry, no...

Answer (score 1):

One workaroud would be to change the route/method signature to

```
[Route("api/user/{domain}/{username}/details")]
public IHttpActionResult(string domain, string username)
{
    // ...
}
```

as this would correctly handle the incomming request...