# %2F is not working for "/" but %3F is working for "?" in Web API uri

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I am using custom function in Restful API to get the specific result.
to get the string with name "ABC?" i am sending below GET request URI

`https://localhost:44372/route/V1/Values/ExistsValue(Name='ABC%3F')/`

this is working fine. but to get the name as "ABC/" i am sending below GET request URI

`https://localhost:44372/route/V1/Values/ExistsValue(Name='ABC%2F')/`

but this doesn't work. it showing error like below

`IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found`

How to handle this?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Did you check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url

Comment: Sorry but didn't work

Comment: i used equivalent Hexadecimal value for request URI and it worked.