# Url problems in MVC C#

Tags: url, model-view-controller

I have a problem in MVC project in url.

In the Route config I have the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Test",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{selected}/{category}/{engineId}‌​",
           defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "SubCategories"}
       );
```

The parameter category contains the name of selected category. In database I have the category with name: "Packet / Set". If in my website I choose this category and in the url will appear this categoryname

```
SubCategories/92/Bertone-FREECLIMBER-2.0/Packet / Set /33720‌%E2%80%8B.
```

I got the

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 The resource cannot be found.
```

error.
If the the category name doesn't contain the "/" character, evrything works fine:

```
SubCategories/94/Bertone-FREECLIMBER-2.0/Air%20filter/33720%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B
```

Could you advise how should I resolve this?

Comment: You need to escape the / in route name, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the all slashes in URL as `%2F`. You can use Javascript encodeURIComponent() function. MVC automatically decodes URL and action parameters so you should be able to get values correctly in your controller without any additional effort.
Take a look here for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp