# Difference in calling asmx webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I had to make a small change in a >4 year old .NET application. After the change an asmx webservice included in the application does not work anymore

- .NET 3.5
- No MVC
- used (the newer) Visual Studio 2017 to do the change
- No (code) changes done to the actual asmx webservice.

Before my change we called the webservice like this:

```
http://server/WS/AuthService.asmx/UserIsAuthenticated?applicationid=24
```

This worked perfectly for many years. Doing 1000's requests a day

After my change we got an 500 error on this webservice. The webservice does work if I call it with the 'op=' parameter like this:

```
http://server/WS/AuthService.asmx?op=UserIsAuthenticated&applicationid=24
```

There seems to be an update in the default 'routing' for asmx webservices. 
Any idea where I can configure the application to use the old syntax `<service>/<operation>` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url

Comment: Hey Marco, I'm not passing a slash '/' as a parameter. This is (was?) the default definition for indicating the webmethod within a service. The only parameter I pass along is the 'applicationid'

Comment: OK, gotta ask, what did you change?

Comment: Is there a `<web services>` section in your web.config? Which protocols?

Comment: You could try removing the `get` protocol and adding `post`.

Comment: The changes made to the solution were not relevant to the asmx. I changed  some css and an ajdustment to the page_load() of the default.aspx. However it's an old solution created with VS2012 i think. I did my changes with VS2017, not 100% sure but I think VS2017 did some 'updates' to the solution.