# C# [HttpPost] string value through angular http.post becomes null

Tags: c#, json, angular, angular7

My C# post method looks

```
[HttpPost]
public void mymethod(string id) {...}
```

I am trying to post string value from angular `http.post` like this but value reaches to C# method as null.

```
const mystr = 'mystring';
this.http.post('myurl', mystr);
```

What I tried

```
{id: mystr}
JSON.stringify({id: mystr})
```

Note: Sending id value with `[HttpGet("{id}")]` works well but mystr may contains '/' value so fails whenever '/' contains.

When I replace mymethod signature to `([FromBody] string id)` I get `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: Use: `this.http.post('myurl/'+mystr);`

Comment: mystr may contain '/' so it wont work all the times.

Comment: then pass it in the request body itself as mentined below!

Comment: if you dont want to declare a class then Get in the `Request-Headers`

Comment: Can you show the how `mystr` looks like?

Comment: const mystr = '3/4th Pipes';

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994100/7124761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use encodeValue on mystr on angular. In C# API id you should get decoded value.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpUrlEncodingCodec

Comment: simple example will be appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not an expert in angular, but in general, you need to change slashes to %2F so they will not be treated by C# as path delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

for your scenario you need a small change, just come with a `Model` of data you want to receive in `POST` request. 
Something like :-

```
public class CustomData {
   string id {get; set;}
}
```

and then tweak your `API` and make it aware that it has to recieve something from from `request's body`

So, instead of

```
[HttpPost]
public void mymethod(string id) {...}
```

use this

```
[HttpPost]
public void mymethod([FromBody] CustomData data) {...}
```

Comment: instead of changing C# method, can we tweak some thing in Angular post mentod?

Answer (score 0):

could you try changing the way you send from angular as the following

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

this.http.post('myurl', 'string value', { headers: headers }) ;
```

if 'applicaiton/json' does not work please try to change it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: I use HttpInterceptor with above HttpHeaders. but no luck.