# 1. Forward slash in routing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url-parameters

I have a GET end point which will take user name as parameter. Below is the action

```
[Route("user/{userName}")]
public User GetUserByName([FromUri] string userName)
{
  // logic here
}
```

This is how i make the request.

```
var restClient = new RestClient("uri");
var request = new RestRequest("user/" + userName);
var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

It worked fine for all cases till a user with name containing forward slash came.
Eg: Akbar/Badhusha
Then the request will looks like **user/Akbar/Badhusha**

This causing the request to return **Not Fount** error

I tried to add the parameter with AddQueryParameter method. All returning Not found error.

1. I also tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode
2. Also tried replacing / with  %2f
3. Also tried user?userName=Akbar/Badhusha

All of them failed.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Does it work if you send as querystring? e.g. `user?userName=Akbar/Badhusha`

Comment: @MKR, it didn't.

Comment: You need to URL encode your `userName`.

Comment: `user?userName=Akbar/Badhusha` will work if you remove `[FromUri]` attribute from parameter.

Comment: You need to allow for double escaping and decode it manually. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994100/6396399).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing **[FromUri]** from the parameter as shown below,

```
[Route("user")]
public User GetUserByName(string userName)
{
  // logic here
}
```

And the request may look like,

> user?userName=Akbar/Badhush