# encoded url as parameter in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I want to set a url as encoded url to REST API. The url I want to my route to look like this

Required: `https://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles?url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.dri.ie%2Fcatalog%2F5999pn33w&format=json`

In the routes.rb I tried to set the route like this:

```
namespace 'api' do
 namespace 'v1' do
  resources :articles
  get 'articles/*url'  => 'articles#show' 
 end
end
```

so my route look like this

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles/https://repository.dri.ie/catalog/5999pn33w

how can I make the url passed as encoded url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Route parameter with slash "/" in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972578/route-parameter-with-slash-in-url)

Comment: Granted that answer isn't using ruby/rails, but the key part is about URL encoding. You can't just put un-encoded forward slashes into the route's path, or they will be treated as separate sections of the path.

Answer (score 2):

You have missidentified the issue here as it has nothing to do with URL encoding. Rails doesn't care about the contents of the query string when matching routes. It just matches the request by path and method.

Thus a request for `https://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles?url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.dri.ie%2Fcatalog%2F5999pn33w&format=json` will alway match the `index` route defined by `resources :articles`. Remember also that routes have priority in the order they are defined.

What you need to do instead is create a route that matches `/articles` [with a constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Custom route to match /articles?url=xxx
  get 'articles',
    to: 'articles#show',
    constraints: ->(request){ request.query_parameters["url"].present? }
  # this must come after the custom route
  resources :articles
end
```